Is it possible to accept file without any key in multipart-formdata? (blank key)
In multipart formdata we accept the parts as with key-value pairs, is it possible to handle request with file without any key?

curl --location --request GET 'endpoint' 
--form '=@"/C:/Users/User/Downloads/test.pdf"' 
--form 'validTill="04/30/2024"'

In case of unkown key, I understand that I can parse HttpServeletRequest to see if there's file. But, is it possible to accept file without any key?

form dat is by design key/value. So if it isn't key/value it isn't form-data but something else.

multipart/form-data is a data format. You can't do that, more than you can use application/json to submit XML.
